# Excel dates with standard format (*) become custom when opened in another country

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Here in the USA, I have created an Excel 2007 spreadsheet with a table that contains several columns with dates. I have formatted the date columns using the standard short date format (with the asterisk). When a coworker in Germany opens the file all the existing rows have the date formatted correctly (in this case day.month.year) but when they add a row to the table the date cells are displayed using a custom format that is similar to the US format. That is, the custom format shows as month.day.year.

If I have the coworker update the format for the entire column and set it to short date, then the problem goes away when adding a row for the coworker in Germany, but when I open the file in the USA and add a row, the short date is now a custom date for me with date/month/year.

I have been able to duplicate this on my machine by setting the region and language of my computer to German.

So my question is has anyone ever seen this behavior before and if so, do they have a workaround?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether this is a known bug and if so, does anyone know of a workaround (I have updated my original post to clarify)

Comment: Try using custom format with `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the outcome that I am trying to avoid. That is, even though I created the column with short date format, when they add a row it becomes a custom format and not a short date format. Thanks anyway.